# Does Mob have an automatic/unconscious psychic protection?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

IIRC in season 1, when he was fighting other psychics, once he was hit someone said he has something like an automatic or unconscious psychic protection that's why he can't get hurt easily even if he's catched offguard. But in season 2 when running he falls and he has his knee bleading and his face bruised. Does Mob have an automatic/unconscious psychic protection?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to when Mob was running during the race and fell. He didn't want to use psychic powers to win the race, he most likely just turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO** to create psychic protection one has to use a strong active mind to create a barrier.

Each time Mob battle with other psychic he give more preference to his **defensive** power which involve it's barrier as his main attack/move.

While in **Annual Marathon Race** Mob decide to finish the race in **top 10** without using his psychic power and later he will confront his feeling to Takane Tsubomi.

This are the dialogue that were exchanged in the presence of **Mob**, **Dimple** and **Mezato-san** (the reporter girl).